# ios share extension - how to get image URL?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I am writing an action extension to transform an image URL and copy to clipboard by clicking the share button of an image on a webpage in Safari.

I created an action extension in Xcode without UI.

In javascript preprocessing script `action.js`, I can get the URL and title of the whole page.

```
    run: function(arguments) {
        
        arguments.completionFunction({
            "URL" : document.URL,
            "title": document.title
        })
    },
```

And that works for the share button of the whole webpage.

But how can I get the URL of the image that is pushed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I had to create an action extension with User Interface so that I am working within `ActionViewController: UIViewController` class.  The trick is to look for `UTType.url.identifier` through the shared items.

The code below works for share button of the whole webpage and an image.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        // search for url
        var found = false
        for item in self.extensionContext!.inputItems as! [NSExtensionItem] {
            for provider in item.attachments! {
                if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.url.identifier) {
                    provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.url.identifier, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) in
                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                                if let url = url as? URL {
                             
          // do something with the url here
                            
                       }

                    }})
                    
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }
            
            if (found) {
                // We only handle one url, so stop looking for more.
                break
            }
        }

        // don't show user interface
        self.done()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use from URL, its better to use from :

```
  pod 'SDWebImage'
```

this is better because of cache

you can Set your URL string with below code:

```
libraryImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "your URL string"),
                                  placeholderImage: UIImage(named: Image.placeholder.rawValue))
```

after that you can get URL with below code:

```
libraryImageView.sd_ImageURL
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is "your URL string" the URL of the image? My question is how to get that in the first place.

Comment: yes, the first part of the code is Setter and in the picture, you can get the URL as you can see the description of the namespace.